# Curious if there are any methods to sum a total based on a weekly classification for a n day period aside from union

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am looking to sum a total based on a case that ranges for a week from query below to accumulate up to 90 day period. I can currently accomplish this by limiting the dates and union them together; however, is there another way?

The given query is only 2 weeks I would have to continue to union more subselects to fulfill 90 days.

```sql
select comp_id, sum(total) from (
(
SELECT CASE
         WHEN AVG(amount) < 10 THEN 0 
         WHEN COUNT(p_id) < SUM(amount)*.5
         THEN SUM(amount)*.5
         ELSE COUNT(p_id) 
        END as total, avg(amount), comp_id
FROM p_container INNER JOIN chg ON chg_p_id = p_id 
INNER JOIN c_type ON c_type_id = chtype_id
where correction_name like '%correction word%'
AND p_date BETWEEN GETDATE () - 9 AND GETDATE () - 2
group by comp_id
) UNION ALL (
SELECT CASE
         WHEN AVG(amount) < 5 THEN 0 
         WHEN COUNT(p_id) < SUM(amount)*.06
         THEN SUM(amount)*.06 
         ELSE COUNT(p_id) 
        END as total, avg(amount), comp_id
FROM p_container INNER JOIN chg ON chg_p_id = p_id 
INNER JOIN c_type ON c_type_id = chtype_id
where correction_name like '%correction word%'
AND p_date BETWEEN GETDATE () - 17  AND GETDATE () - 10 
group by comp_id
)) group by comp_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case` expressions:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN p_date BETWEEN GETDATE() - 9 AND GETDATE() - 2 THEN 'group1'
             WHEN p_date BETWEEN GETDATE() - 17 AND GETDATE() - 10 THEN 'group2'
        END) as grp,
       (CASE WHEN AVG(amount) < 10 THEN 0 
             WHEN COUNT(p_id) < SUM(amount)*0.5 THEN SUM(amount)*0.5
              ELSE COUNT(p_id) 
        END) as total, AVG(amount),
       comp_id
FROM p_container INNER JOIN
     chg
     ON chg_p_id = p_id INNER JOIN
     c_type
     ON c_type_id = chtype_id
WHERE correction_name like '%correction word%' AND
      p_date >= GETDATE() - 17 
GROUP BY grp, comp_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a big start towards what I am trying to do.